# Tags are not being saved when using django-parler

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, django-parler

I am using `django-parler` for translation and `django-taggit` for adding tags. But when I add tags inside translation field (because of using in multiple language) tags are not being saved in admin page.
**models.py**

```py
class News(models.Model):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title=models.CharField(max_length=255),
        content=RichTextUploadingField(),
        tags=TaggableManager(),
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True),
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```